# i am trying to using google translator and translate it is happening when i choosing the output language English or Hindi but when select odia

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, file-handling, google-translation-api

I am trying to using google translator and translate it is happening when I choosing the output language English or Hindi but when select odia.

```py
from google_trans_new import google_translator  

translator = google_translator()
  
translate_text = translator.translate('สวัสดีจีน',lang_tgt='or')  

file = open ('samp.txt','w')

file.write(translate_text)

file.close()

print(translate_text)
```

**Output**

```
eturn codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: character maps to <undefined>
```

How to solve this

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `encoding` to `utf-8` for `open` like this

```
file = open('samp.txt','w',encoding='utf-8')
```

You can read more about encoding [here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), error for you program is wrong coding which is system dependent for `open`. When you are running the code on Linux there will be no error. But, when running on Windows you need to explicitly mention the `encoding` parameter.